How to rename the CSV file based upon the column name inside the file using shell script
Let's assume I have list of CSV files under the folder called /path/RAS, each CSV file is going to carry the information about each customer.
Let's take one customer file as example:
Customer_Name,Customer_id,Customer_Address,Customer_PhoneNumber,Customer_Sale
AAAA,A1090,POl,XXXXX,89080

My expected output:
I need to rename the file as AAAA.csv, similarly I need to rename the CSV file which is available inside the folder /path/RAS with respective Customer_Name.csv
cat AAAA.csv
Customer_Name,Customer_id,Customer_Address,Customer_PhoneNumber,Customer_Sale
AAAA,A1090,POl,XXXXX,89080

I got a code
awk -F, '{print > ($1".csv")}' originalFile.csv

The above code assumes the first column for renaming, is there is a way to rename the file based upon the column name for our case "Customer_Name", in my real case scenario there are huge no of column and column position may vary in future, and also i need to loop this functionality for each file in the folder.

It's unclear how to answer your question due to the ambiguous line breaks added by the website. Please edit your question and place the example CSV file headers and shell script inside fenced code blocks or indent them with four spaces at the beginning of each line that should be displayed verbatim. To change the field your awk command uses for the file name, alter the $1 in the command to match the column number you wish to extract; awk -F, '{print > ($3".csv")}' would create a file named Customer_Address.csv given your example.

So you have given a column name. You need to search in the first line of the CSV, which field it is in. Then you have the field number. With this you know which field of the second line you have to extract.

What if you have identical customer names?  Wouldn't it be safer to name files after the customer ID assuming that is your unique identifier? Or at least name the files a concatenation of both.

If your CSV files are "simple" ones (no quoted fields with commas or newlines, etc.), if they all have only a header line and a data line, then the following may work:
awk -F, 'FNR==1 {h=$0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i == "Customer_Name") break}
         FNR==2 {print h ORS $0 > ("/path/RAS/" $i ".csv")}' /path/RAS/*.csv

If your CSV files are more complex you should consider using a real CSV tool kit, or a recent version of GNU awk and its CSV parsing capabilities: simply replace -F, with --csv (or the quivalent -k).

It sounds like this might be what you're trying to do, untested, using any awk:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /path/RAS || exit 1

awk -F',' '
    FNR == 1 {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( $i == "Customer_Name" ) {
                fldNr = i
                break
            }
        }
        hdr = $0
        next
    }
    { out = $fldNr ".csv" }
    out != prev {
        close(prev)
        prev = out
        print hdr > out
    }
    { print > out }
' *.csv

That assumes the input file can contain multiple customer names, that lines are grouped by customer name, and that a customer name can only appear in 1 input file. If any of that is wrong, then fix your question to include all of your requirements and more truly representative sample input/output.
You'll need to add checks for an output file already existing if that's a concern, and add code to remove the input file(s) if you want. Personally I'd write the output to a different directory than the input.
